# Using different page templates in TYPO3

Tags: templates, typo3

I'm looking for some help about using different templates for each page. I'm using everything is on the TYPO3 video tutorial (linked below) but isn't explain there how to do what I need (which code must be write and where).

[Site Package tutorial part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtBmim7pc0o)

[Site Package tutorial part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deSMVfCSCXY&t=9s)

[Site Package tutorial part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEoWOBT0rQE&t=181s)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to start with the site package builder: https://sitepackagebuilder.com/ based on Bootstrap package which will a) bring you already helpful templates and b) shows you how to make your own ones (Example.html / Configuration/TsConfig/Page/Mod/Weblayout/BackendLayout.tsconfig).

Some helpful references: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/FluidTemplates/Index.html

Comment: EH! this is exactly the way followed and described in my post above!
what I need is what they didn't show in the tutorial.
how to use different defalut template, for a different page.

Comment: are you using the site package with or without bootstrap package?

Answer (score 0):

### Connecting Fluid templates to Backend Layouts

So you have a special template for the *about* page and want to use it in TYPO3. You'll have to create a new Backend Layout for this template.

The **Backend Layout** could be configured in *Page TSconfig* like that:

```
mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts {
    about {
        title = About page
        config {
            backend_layout {
                colCount = 1
                rowCount = 1
                rows {
                    1 {
                        columns {
                            1 {
                                name = main column
                                colPos = 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        icon = EXT:your_sitepackage/Resources/Public/Images/BackendLayouts/About.svg
    }
}
```

In the next step, you'll have to connect your new Backend Layout with your template. This is done in TypoScript setup:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
        file.stdWrap.cObject {
            // select a layout template depending on the page's BackendLayout:
            key.data = pagelayout
            // Important! If you set BackendLayouts through TSconfig, you MUST use the prefix 'pagets__':
            pagets__1_column = TEXT
            pagets__1_column.value = EXT:your_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/1Column.html
            pagets__about = TEXT
            pagets__about.value = EXT:your_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/About.html
            default = TEXT
            default.value = EXT:your_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/1Column.html
        }

        layoutRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:your_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        }

        partialRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:your_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Partials/
        }

        variables {

        }
    }
}
```

### Official video tutorial

See also the YouTube video about this topic: [How to implement frontend layouts in TYPO3 using backend layouts](https://youtu.be/RoHaeo4fq34)

---

### Finally, assign your new Backend Layout to single pages in TYPO3 backend

This is done in the page properties:

1. Open the **page properties** of a page in the TYPO3 Backend.
2. In the tab *'Appearance'*, you will find two options to assign Backend Layouts:

   1. 'Backend Layout (this page only)'
   2. 'Backend Layout (subpages of this page)'

These are pretty much self-explanatory:

- The first option sets the desired Backend Layout **only for this single page**.
- The second option will assign the Backend Layout **for all sub pages of the current page**. You can override this Backend Layout again: open the page properties of the sub page where you want a different layout and assign a new one.

[On this website](http://typo3buddy.com/typo3-template-tutorial/fluid/assign-backend-layouts-to-pages/) you can find an even more detailed explanation with screenshots (taken from the Backend of TYPO3 6.2).

Comment: yes, this is I know, with bootstrap I have alot of choice, but this not what I want.
I don't want to use bootstrap.
I want to assign for example for page about us, template file about.html.

Comment: You don't have to use Bootstrap. Please see my updated answer. You can compare this explanation (and the YouTube video) with the [example site package](https://github.com/sebkln/basetemplate9) I showed you in your other question.